# Keep "Full screen" button in preview while opening PDF with standard application (not office web apps)?

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps, pdf, preview

We currently changed the configuration of our `SharePoint 2013` server, so that clicking on a link of a PDF file in search results does now open the PDF file in `Office Web Applications`, but in the pdf viewer application defined on the device of the user (e. g. Adobe Reader).

Unfortunately, at the same time the "**Full Screen**" button on the preview pane was **greyed out** and can not be used.

Consequence: I can preview a document in the search results and scroll through it, but I can not open it in the browser (office web applications) in Full Screen Mode any more:
[image]

Is there a way to get both at the same time?

1. default: opening pdf files in the standard pdf viewer application of the user's device (NOT with Office Web Applications)
2. by clicking on the "Full Screen" button (or maybe another trick) displaying the pdf file at the maximum size which fits the current browser window in Office Web Applications?